# How to get a S' with a subscript at the correct position

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

I want to create the symbol `S'_\geq`, but the lower `\geq` is placed too far right.

If I use `S^'_\geq`, the `'` is too far up, but the `\geq` is in the right position.

How can I get an `S'` with a subscript `\geq` placed as if I used `S_\geq^i`?

Comment: I see no difference in the placement of the subscript in `S'_{\geq}` or `S_{\geq}^{i}` (see the [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v8KnS.png))

Comment: i get the same result as egreg; nothing i do will make the subscript budge from the "expected" position.  are you perhaps using some fonts other than computer modern?

Comment: If you get a different result, please add a minimal example of code that shows the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts guys, the problem was the software. Seems like GeoGebra handles LaTeX slightly different than texlive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `'` becomes `^{\prime}`, thus that the subscript also goes to `S`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  S'_\geq = S^{\prime}_{\geq}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Possible reasons, why it does not work for your document:

- The apostrophe is the wrong character. It should be the ASCII character apostrophe at position 39 (0x27).
- A package (or other code) changes, how the apostrophe behaves in math mode.

Comment: Thank you, worked. The problem was probably the software, used latex in GeoGebra, seems to behave differently there.

Answer (score 1):

There is also math mode  command `\prime`. Usage: $S_\geq^\prime$.

Comment: The inputs `S'` and `S^{\prime}` are completely equivalent.